# rspec click a span

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am using rspec to test some pages and would like to use the click method. However the DOM doesn't have the link or button. it's just a span and magically it becomes a link with javascript.

```
<span class="footerLink feedbackLink">
    Feedback
</span>
```

rspec offers "click_link" and "click_button"

any ideas how I could click a span?

Comment: When you say "magically becomes a link" do you mean that you attach a onclick handler with Javascript or you change the element type to be an anchor from a span after some Javascript code runs?

Comment: Yes, sorry for using "magically." onclick even is being attached. Frankly I think it would have been easier to just have a link there but that's the current design

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cucumber and Capybara, clicking a non-link or button element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3585533/841064)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
find('.feedbackLink').click
```

[`find`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) returns an Element, and the Element class has a [`#click`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#click-instance_method) method.

Since you probably are handling the click in Javascript, don't forget to add `:js => true` as a metatag on your test.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer: I added specify "sends feedback", js: true do and find('.feedbackLink').click. But it opens Firefox. is there a way to skip that and run it just as any other test in rspec?

Comment: @SarahA unfortunately, if it depends on Javascript, it needs to run in a browser.  The good news is that the browser doesn't have to be Firefox -- [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) is one among several headless options.

Comment: Yeah, you can ignore js specs: `rspec --tags ~js`

And Capybara (the tester backend of RSpec) can use https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit what is a headless version of WebKit rendering engine.