# Click "Edit" button use selenium cucumber ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, click, cucumber

I want to update information for Work, Education, Basic information, Contact Information in profile (accounts.google.com)

I have file "Testcases.feature"

Scenario: User can update information for Work

```
Given I launch "https://accounts.google.com" page
When I fill in "Email" with "abc123@gmail.com"
And I fill in "Passwd" with "abc@2013"
And I click on "signIn" button
And I click on "Edit profile" link
And I click on "Edit" button
Then I should see text "abc..."
```

I can't click "Edit" button because existing many "Edit" button in site

When i run cmd: `cucumber -r features features\Testcases.feature` --> Appear error below:

> And I click on "Edit" button                                # features/step_
>   definitions/lib_web.rb:9
>         Unable to find button "Edit" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
>         ./features/step_definitions/lib_web.rb:10:in `/^I click on "(.*)" button$/
>   '     features\Testcases.feature:65:in`And I click on "Edit" button'

Comment: Whats the code you're using to select the edit button?

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one button with "Edit" label I would recommend adding new step for clicking using selector as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3889673/1189894) and then using it in your story like this:

```
When I click within "#buttonId"
```

You can replace "#buttonId" with any other selector you find more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use *Within* here as below

```
within "#specific area" do
  click_button "edit"
end
```